# How do I send input to a process in C?

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to run git push from C:

```
system("git push");
```

And when it asks for

```
username:
password:
```

I want to give it back a username, and a github auth token. How would I accomplish this? I've tried to look around for a solution, but I can't seem to get the wording right when I Google the problem. Note that I have the username and the auth token stored in `char*`'s:

```
char *username = "whatever";
char *token = "whatever";
system("git push");
```

Comment: Uh, I don't think an auth token lets you push, does it? Consider using a private key instead.

Comment: Yeah it does, I've tested it. And the reference says you can :)

Comment: There are probably better ways to authenticate yourself with a git repository.

Comment: Can you give me any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to send input data to the process if it was created using `system(char *command);` (or maybe is possible, but I think is too hard), you need to create a new process with `popen(const char *command, const char *type);`. ([popen documentation here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen)). This is a little exmaple that I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char username[] = "something";
    char password[] = "something";
    FILE *pf; // file descriptor of the git process

    pf = popen("git push", "w"); // create git process in write mode

    if (!pf) {
        printf("Process couldn't be created!");
        return 1;
    }

    // this will send username and password (and the '\n' char too) to the git process
    fputs(username, pf);
    fputs(password, pf);
    pclose(pf); // close git process

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
execv can be used to accomplish this .

 int execv(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

Example :
The following example illustrates the use of execv to execute the ls shell command:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  main()
  {
     pid_t pid;
     char *const parmList[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "/u/userid/dirname", NULL};

     if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        perror("fork error");
     else if (pid == 0) {
        execv("/bin/ls", parmList);
        printf("Return not expected. Must be an execv error.n");
     }
  }
```

you can change on the basis of your code

Comment: This looks like it's for parameters for commands, not for input to a command?